# I always get the README file in cmd rather than commands if I type commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make a program in Windows, and whenever you type "commands" or anything else, it always shows you the README file. Nothing else.
I have tried adding quotes to the commands in the cmd file, but that still didn't work. I'm using Windows 8.1 x64.

Prototype.cmd:

```
@echo off
set version=1.0.0 ALPHA
title Prototype version %version%
echo Welcome to Prototype!
echo You have to change the User Directory in the command file to your username.
timeout 1 > NUL
IF NOT EXIST C:\Users\OldBo-5\Desktop\Prototype\System GOTO SYSTEMNOTFOUND
timeout 5 > NUL
cls
:PrototypeMain
echo Type "commands" to get a list of commands.
echo Type "README" to get the readme text file.
timeout 1 > NUL
set /p cmd=">"
cd C:\Users\OldBo-5\Desktop\Prototype\System\Commands
if %cmd% == "readme" goto :ReadmeCmd
:ReadmeCmd
notepad C:\Users\OldBo-5\Desktop\Prototype\READ ME.text
cls
goto PrototypeMain
if %cmd% == "commands" goto :HelpCmd
:HelpCmd
cls
echo "COMMANDS" - Shows this.
echo "README" - Shows readme.text
timeout 10 > NUL
goto PrototypeMain
:SYSTEMNOTFOUND
cls
title Error starting Prototype.
echo Error starting Prototype. Error Code: 4 - System directory not found. Output error log to ROOT\ErrorLog.text
echo Did you forget to install?
echo To open, right click and click Edit. Select Notepad.
cd C:\Users\OldBo-5\Desktop\Prototype\
type NUL > ErrorLog.text
echo Prototype failed to boot. Error Code: 4 > ErrorLog.text
echo Reason: Error Code 4 means that the system directory could not be found. >> ErrorLog.text
timeout 5 > NUL
exit
```

Comment: Hint: What does `if %cmd% == "readme" goto :ReadmeCmd` do if `%cmd%` is not `"readme"`?

Comment: It still goes to the readme file, anyway. @melpomene

Comment: This is definitely not a [mcve] to demonstrate your issue!

Comment: Have you ever heard of doublequotes, because you certainly need them when there's spaces or certain poison characters in a file or directory path, i.e. `notepad "C:\Users\OldBo-5\Desktop\Prototype\READ ME.text"`

Comment: It appears to me that you very much don't understand batch files or their syntax.  A good place to start might be [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_syntax.htm).  Do yourself a favor and get the basics down before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you?

```
@Echo Off
Set "version=1.0.0 ALPHA"
Title Prototype version %version%
CD /D "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Prototype" 2>NUL||Exit /B
Echo Welcome to Prototype!
Timeout 1 >NUL
If Not Exist "System\" GoTo SYSTEMNOTFOUND

:PrototypeMain
ClS
Set "cmnd="
Echo To get a list of commands type COMMANDS 
Echo To get the ReadMe text file type README
Set /P "cmnd=>"
If /I "%cmnd%" == "readme" (
    Notepad "READ ME.text"
) Else If /I "%cmnd%" == "commands" (
    ClS
    Echo COMMANDS - Shows this.
    Echo README - Shows readme.text
    Timeout 10 >NUL
)
GoTo PrototypeMain

:SYSTEMNOTFOUND
ClS
Title Error starting Prototype.
Echo Error starting Prototype. Error Code: 4 - System directory not found. Output error log to ErrorLog.text
Echo Did you forget to install?
(   Echo Prototype failed to boot. Error Code: 4
    Echo Reason: Error Code 4 means that the system directory could not be found.
)>"ErrorLog.text"
Timeout 5 >NUL
Exit /B
```